F7 key being pressed - how to find source?
About once a day, F7 will be pressed. Ctrl or Space often seems to be the trigger, but it can happen at any time. This is very weird, and affects all applications on my desktop (Kate, Firefox, VSCode, konsole, etc). I had though it was something to do with KDE because I don't notice this happening in MATE/GNOME environments, but KDE folks seem unenthused: https://discuss.kde.org/t/weird-f7-issues/14589/8
How can I determine what application or input source is pressing F7? I can run xev, but that only shows that it has happened, not who did it.
Running X11 plasma on Debian 12 when this happens.

Sounds like a faulty keyboard... attach another keyboard, remove the existing one (possibly using unbind if it can't be unplugged), see if it still happens or not...?
